# Unable to bring up appserver

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, sqljdbc

Getting below error when tried to start the server

I'm using apache 7.0.57 and SQLJDBC 8.2, can't use mssql-jdbc-9.2.0.jre8.jar as that is not supported by my platform.

SEVERE: Unable to connect to database.  Will only use properties from file.
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The authenticationScheme NTLM is not valid.)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at com.pega.pegarules.internal.bootstrap.PRBootstrapDataSource.getBootstrapPropertiesFromDB(PRBootstrapDataSource.java:669)
at com.pega.pegarules.internal.bootstrap.PRBootstrapDataSource.getBootstrapPropertiesFromDB(PRBootstrapDataSource.java:652)
at com.pega.pegarules.internal.bootstrap.PRBootstrapDataSource.getBootstrapProperties(PRBootstrapDataSource.java:629)
at com.pega.pegarules.internal.bootstrap.PRBootstrapDataSource.getBootstrapProperties(PRBootstrapDataSource.java:623)
at com.pega.pegarules.internal.bootstrap.PRBootstrap.(PRBootstrap.java:119)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.pega.pegarules.boot.internal.extbridge.AppServerBridgeToPega.checkForStartup(AppServerBridgeToPega.java:116)
at com.pega.pegarules.boot.internal.extbridge.AppServerBridgeToPega.invokeMethodPropagatingThrowable(AppServerBridgeToPega.java:222)
at com.pega.pegarules.boot.internal.extbridge.AppServerBridgeToPega.invokeMethod(AppServerBridgeToPega.java:272)
at com.pega.pegarules.internal.web.servlet.WebAppLifeCycleListenerBoot.contextInitialized(WebAppLifeCycleListenerBoot.java:83)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The authenticationScheme NTLM is not valid.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationScheme.valueOfString(SQLServerDriver.java:683)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:663)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
... 28 more

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,  you are trying to connect mysql database server.

Your DB is mysql,  and you try to use mssql jdbc driver to connect.
that's seems impossible.
Please use a matched version of mysql jdbc driver to connect to your mysql database.